# How to call another function from a function

Tags: python

- My First function is addition of program

  ```
  def addn(x,y):
   return (x + y)
  ```
- My second function is output got from the first function `+ 2`

  ```
  def addn2(x,y)
    return (x+y+2)
  ```

Instead of above searching for anything like below, with out re writing everything in the second function

```
def addn3(x,y):
    return (addn + 2)
```

Comment: You call a function by writing parentheses and putting the arguments inside, separated by commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters are important:

```
def addn3(x, y):
    return (addn(x, y) + 2)
```